# Reply to message without pinging

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I make my bot reply to a message without pinging the author? I know how to make it reply but I don't know how to make it avoid pinging the author. This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```py
ctx.reply, mention (ctx.author)= False
```

Comment: my bot, i made a bot and i want to know how to make it reply to a message without pinging, im using discord.py

Answer (score 2):

Make a `,` after the message/string and add `mention_author=False`.

This is an example :

```py
ctx.reply("Message") # To reply (But it ping the author)

ctx.reply("Message", mention_author=False) # To reply (But it doesn't ping the author)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic question! Okay, so every `discord.abc.Messageable` now has a reply attribute. To reply, simply use:

```py
await ctx.reply('Message')
```

You also have the option to not mention the author in the reply with, mention_author=False. Example below:

```py
await ctx.reply(mention_author=False)
```

Hope this helps. For more information [visit the discord.py documents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=reply#discord.ext.commands.Context.reply)

Comment: `discord.abc.Messageable` doesn't have a reply attribute or function. Replying to a message uses `discord.abc.Messageable.send` with the reference argument

Comment: how would i do it with an embed?         this doesnt work: await ctx.reply(mention_author=False)(embed=embed)

Comment: @SammyTM `await ctx.send(embed=embed, mention_author=False`, but it seems you don't really know how python works. I suggest [doing a tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) before asking more questions here

Answer (score 0):

`discord.Message.reply()` is a shortcut method to `discord.abc.Messageable.send()` to reply to the Message. This function has an argument called `mention_author` (default `None`). Setting this to `False` makes sure the author of the message you're responding to doesn't get mentioned/pinged

```py
await ctx.reply(mention_author=False)
```

[reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=reply#discord.ext.commands.Context.reply)

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: @JeremyCaney The current top answer has a good explanation, but sure I'll edit it. Thanks for the heads up!